# TypeScript: Can I set a group a list of strings within a type and use that on a different interface?

Tags: typescript

I am new to TypeScript and would like some guidance on an issue that I am having. I have an Icon component that should accept a string containing the name of the Icon. However, I would like to set up the possible accepted strings within a Type/Interface. When I have this current set up, it errors to me that "Type 'string' is not assignable to type Icon".

I'm not sure if this is even possible or is a good practice and would appreciate some guidance or some documentation on where I can find similar patterns if possible!

```js
type Icon = {
  'burger-menu': string;
  sort: string;
  'arrow-forward': string;
  'play-filled': string;
  'swap-horizontal': string;
  heart: string;
  close: string;
};

export interface Props {
  /**
   * The name of the SVG
   */
  icon: Icon;
}


//

In the component:

const Button: FC<Props> = ({ buttonType = 'default'}: Props) => (
  <button type={type} onClick={() => onClick()}>
    {label}
    <Icon icon="burger-menu" /> // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Icon'.
  </button>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do that instead:

```
type Icon =
  | 'burger-menu'
  | 'sort'
  | 'arrow-forward'
  | 'play-filled'
  | 'swap-horizontal'
  | 'heart'
  | 'close';


export interface Props {
    /**
     * The name of the SVG
     */
    icon: Icon;
}
```